# Support with rewrite URL in patterns

Tags: .htaccess

I have this URL format:

```
https://www.example.com/shows/my_personal_show_2.0_34565.htm
```

Where the tailing number is the database reference, I need to rewrite it to:

```
https://www.example.com/shows/my-personal-show-2.0-my-personal-show.htm
```

We have thousands of indexed URLs by Google and need it to be rewritten via in .htaccess rules with 301 redirect to make it more SEO friendly without harming the SERP very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give some more examples? the rewrite pattern not obvious.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, I was meaning that I do not understand how I will split with regex matching pattern, because different URLs have different length and number of words separated by underscores. But all have the tailing database reference which starts from number 1 to a 5 digits number like _32262.htm I need to rewrite this unfriendly URL to a SEO friendly URL.

Comment: any server side language are you using?

Comment: Hello, scripting is PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take SO as an example, the URL has this format:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077576/support-with-rewrite-url-in-patterns
```

To make a SEO friendly URL, you can rewrite the URL to:

```
https://www.example.com/shows/34565/my-personal-show-2.0
```

To start, you can write your own router and map the above URL to the actual existing file:

**.htacccess**

```
RewriteRule ^shows/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /router.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```

`$1` is the back-reference to the regex part `([0-9]+)` and `$2` is the back-reference to the regex part `(.+)`.

For the **router.php**, you can check if the given `id` and `slug` map to the existing **htm file**.

**router.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['slug'])) {
    $file_path = 'shows/' . str_replace('-', '_', $_GET['slug']) . '_' . $_GET['id'] . '.htm';
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
        readfile($file_path);
    }
    else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
    exit;
}
```

The last thing is that you should make a permanently redirect of the SEO unfriendly URL to SEO friendly URL.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shows/(.+)\_([0-9]+)\.htm$
RewriteRule ^ /redirect.php?id=%2&slug=%1 [QSA,L]
```

**redirect.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['slug'])) {
    $redirectURL = '/shows/' . intval($_GET['id']) . '/' . str_replace('_', '-', $_GET['slug']);
    header('location: ' . $redirectURL, true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. That's what I was looking for!